# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\sb\templates\skm\index.php on line 1003

Tags: php, joomla

i am trying to revamp joomla website on my local host, after changing the details in configuration file, i am getting the following error.

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\templates\skm\index.php on line 1003`

Line 1003 is the last line of the following code

```
<?php
    $spotlight = array ('social');
    $botsl = jaTpl_calSpotlight ($spotlight,jaTpl_isOP()?100:99.5);
    if( $botsl ) {
    ?>
    <!-- BOTTOM SPOTLIGHT-->
    <div id="botsl1" class="wrap">
        <div class="main clearfix">
            <div class="main-inner1 clearfix">

          <?php if( $this->countModules('social') ) {?>
          <div class="ja-box ja-box<?php echo $botsl['social']['class']; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $botsl['social']['width']; ?>;">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="social" style="xhtml" />
          </div>
          <?php } ?>          
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- //BOTTOM SPOTLIGHT -->
        <?php } ?>
    <div id="footer1" class="wrap1">
        <div class="main clearfix">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer1" style="xhtml" />
            <!--    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="xhtml" />  -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/js/wall.js"></script>
</body>
<script>
    /* var ifr='<?php echo JRequest::getVar('ifr'); ?>';

    var last_clicked;

    window.onclick = function(e) {
        last_clicked = e.target;

        if (last_clicked.href) {
            var new_url = last_clicked.href+"&ifr=true";
            // alert(new_url);
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location = new_url;
            last_clicked = '';

        }
    } */
</script>
</html>
<?php } 

?>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing curly bracket

Comment: Missing? Or one too many?

Comment: You have an extra closed curly bracket. You've already closed it after `<!-- //BOTTOM SPOTLIGHT -->`. Any decent IDE such as netbeans will show you where you've gone wrong.

Comment: @putvande PHP doesn't care how many opening brackets you have.. only that they're all closed. http://codepad.org/ke07rlWb

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the comments, you are missing one or many closing brackets.

I recommend you to use another way of doing `else-if` statements to avoid mistakes like this when using HTML like so:

```
<?php if($this->countModules('social')):?>
    <!-- your HTML -->
<?php elseif($this->countModules('anotherInput')):?>
    <!-- your HTML -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also works with `for` and `foreach` statements.